# Variavel inteira pode receber uma condicional como valor?

Tags: delphi

Tenho uma situação onde acontece algo assim:

```
procedure FrmTeste.Teste;
var
   iSinc: LongInt;
const
   ACAO_PROX: LongInt = $0008;
begin
   iSinc := iSinc or ACAO_PROX;
end;
```

Eu não consegui compreender qual valor recebe iSinc ao entrar nessa função, o que de fato acontece?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essa variável vai receber um valor `BOOLEANO`, essa atribuição seria o mesmo que:

```
if (iSinc or ACAO_PROX) then
  iSinc := True
else
  iSinc := False;
```

Se você fazer a conversão, a resposta será `TRUE` ou `FALSE`:

```
procedure FrmTeste.Teste;
var
   iSinc: LongInt;
const
   ACAO_PROX: LongInt = $0008;
begin
   iSinc := iSinc or ACAO_PROX;
   ShowMessage(BoolToStr(Boolean(iSinc)));
end;
```

Comment: Mas o que significa ela fazer essa comparação, o que vai dizer se iSinc é true, ou Acao_prox é true?

Comment: Editei a resposta

Comment: Tudo bem, entendi até então, mas o que quero saber é: iSinc pode ser true por ser uma número inteiro positivo?

Comment: @William não sei Delphi, mas C e outras linguagens assumem que 0 é falso e qualquer outra coisa é verdadeiro. Então, se Delphi assumir esse comportamento também, um numérico pode ser tratado como booleano

Comment: Exatamente isso @JeffersonQuesado no Delphi é mesma coisa, 0 é false e qualquer outro número inteiro é true